# Avoiding glyph collision with Baskervaldx and BibLaTeX

Tags: fonts, biblatex

I have found that there is an ugly "collision" of the glyph for "j" right after an opening parenthesis glyph. This does not happen with "J" when typeset "regularly", but it does, and it is much worse than with "j", when typesetting proceeds through BibLaTeX. Please, compile the MWE below to see what I mean.

How can these flaws (they are so to me) be systematically, or "programmatically", corrected?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}


\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
  @Book{John,
    author = { John },
    title = {A Title},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
(j) (J) against \autocite{John}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The font defines `(` and `J` as a kerning pair (with a kern of 1.62pt); but, between `(` and `J` in the `\autocite` part, the two characters are separated by a whatsit (a `\write` command), so the implicit kern is not applied. In my opinion, the `\write` should be before the `(`.

Comment: Not related, but the package name is `Baskervaldx.sty` and on case sensitive systems your example will not run.

Comment: @egreg: My mistake. I didn't check the case of the style file name because on my system (MikTeX) it runs with all-lowercase. I have edited it according to your comment.

Comment: @egreg: What would you suggest to amend the biblatex-related issue? And, about "(j" (lowercase)?

Comment: That seems a bug in `biblatex`. The other problem is that the font doesn't define `(` and `j` as a kerning pair (it should).

Comment: @egreg: A workaround for the `biblatex` issue would make for an answer. I think that the other issue can be amended via the microtype tools (I'm compiling on `pdfLaTeX`), but you might know of a better approach.

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/598

Comment: @egreg: Oh, great. Thank you very much for your efforts. If your link is appropriate as an answer, I'll happily check it.

Comment: Check if the current versions of the font from ADF's website define the missing kern. If not, report the problem to the font designer. (But do not send TeX, as the font designer is[was] not a TeX user, or rely on the copies currently on CTAN, which may not be current.)

Comment: @cfr: The only chance I've found at the ADF site to get the metrics for the Type 1 fonts is by following a link to the files in the CTAN repository, where there is a kern pair for "parenleft J" but not for "parenleft j".

Comment: @Marcos You can check the kerning table for the opentype or truetype font in FontForge or similar. The reason I say this is because sometimes some kerning pairs have to be discarded during the conversion process. This can't be avoided and the conversion tools generally do it automatically. In this case, the conversion tells you it has discarded them, but since you cannot keep all of them, you are stuck with the reduction.

Comment: Also, it matters whether the type1 versions are current or not. If the opentype/truetype have been updated, they aren't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the reasons for this are so deeply rooted in the ways `biblatex` works and TeX applies kerning that I don't see a way to solve this and similar problems properly.

As [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) [points out in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378565/avoiding-glyph-collision-with-baskervaldx-and-biblatex#comment938288_378565) the kerning between `(` and `J` defined in the font is not applied here.

Kerning and ligatures are not only inhibited by `\write`s (which `biblatex` needs to make use of at times), but also by even very simple grouping and assignments, as demonstrated in

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
f\immediate\write\@auxout{}i\ (\immediate\write\@auxout{}J\ 
\makeatother
%
f\def\foo{bar}i\ (\def\foo{bar}J\ 
%
f\begingroup i\endgroup\ (\begingroup J\endgroup\ 
%
f\bgroup i\egroup\ (\bgroup J\egroup\ 
%
fi\ (J
\end{document}
```

[image]

This was also discussed in egreg's bug report at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/598

I see no way to get rid of all of these kerning-critical infrastructure in `biblatex` while preserving its functionality short of a complete rewrite.